# jquery contains selector not working for \ (Back Slash)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

jquery contains selector not working for \ (back slash). Please find the code below

**Java Script:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("p:contains(Example:\\servername)").css("background-color", "yellow");
   
});
```

**HTML**

```
<p>Example:\\servername</p>
```

Comment: `$("p:contains(Example:\servername)")` must be a string like this `$("p:contains('Example:\servername')")`

Comment: It is Working for $("p:contains(Example:servername)").css("background-color", "yellow");. but not working for $("p:contains('Example:\servername')")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("p:contains('Example:\\\\\\\\\\servername')").css("background-color", "yellow");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Example:\\servername</p>
```

8 and 10 backslashes work properly
but when its 2 only one will escape other and it doesn't make sense when there are four also you get no result but 8 and 10 works and its not good idea to write all of those back slashes what you to do is to write one only followed by none character this doesn't cause any error

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("p:contains('Example:\')").css("background-color", "yellow");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Example:\\servername</p>
```

Comment: In my case "the value inside contains" comes from database

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the `\` need escaping with another `\` and I don't think you can do it with `:contains` selector.

You can do it using `filter()`

```js
let p=$("p").filter(function(){    
   return $(this).text().includes('Example:\\\\servername')
}).css("background-color", "yellow");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Example:\\servername</p>
```

Comment: I've managed to paint the css with contains with too much escaping which probably makes it a bad approach haha `$("p:contains('Example:\\\\\\\\servername')")` this work as well

Comment: @FedeSc: Your Solution Worked For my scenario. Thank You